# Submit button before delete data, reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, submit, delete-row

I'm looking for the answer on how to add to this function a submit button before deletion. Part of my code:

```
// func
const deleteData = id => {
    setEditing(false);
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .delete();
  };

------------------
// and the button without submit option
<button onClick={() => props.deleteData(props.item.id)} />
```

Comment: So you want to call a `submit()` function before the `deleteData()` function?

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: @AlDuncanson, exacly.I want to call a submit before deleteData :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee achieving one function call after another you'd want to write them asynchronously.

This can be done with `async/await`.

Try out this code snippet!

```js
// this will be your submit function
const yourSubmitFunction = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // simulate waiting for a submit
    setTimeout(() => {
    
      // resolve after submission
      resolve('submitted!')
    }, 2000)
  })
};

// asynchronous function
const asyncCall = async () => {
  console.log('waiting for submit...')
  const result = await yourSubmitFunction()
  console.log(result)
  
  // .. now you can call your delete function
}

// click and call your asynchronous function
asyncCall()
```